# Basic Cartesian prodcuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, products

I am having some issues grasping basic ideas of Cartesian products.

I am reading a PDF my professor gave us explain sets/Cartesian products.

If $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ can be written as $\mathbb{R}^2$ then would $S^5$ be written $S \times  S \times  S \times  S \times  S$?

another question he asks us to do is describe the terms in the expression of $(x+1)^5$ and going with my line of thought on what $S^5$ is, I ended up doing $(x+1) (x+1) (x+1) (x+1)$ and multiplying them and taking that product putting it in a table with the remaining $(x+1)$ to get the elements of $(x+1)^5$

There is no textbook for this class and we had 2 snow days this week so I couldn't ask any questions in class (plus all the reading I'm doing online is making me more confused)

so if you guys could tell me if I am on the right path or show me where my "logic" is messed up I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: this is NOT homework, just questions asked to guide our understanding of notes.

Thanks!

Comment: @omnomnomnom thanks for editing! I may have to use the math section of stacked more often than not this semester. I will make sure to put more time in properly formating my questions in the future

Comment: I am unaware of your background. Your two questions are not related. The second is a result of Binomial theorem if you know it.The first idea is right, though I fail to see where you are going with that.Taking Cartesian products is trying to construct a new space from a set of given spaces(maybe copies of a single space like $R$) in a certain way. That is all

Comment: You're welcome for my contribution, but it wasn't all me.  At any rate, if you're interested in learning how to format the math stuff, I recommend taking a look at [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Vishesh My background on this that it is the first time I am seeing any of this. in the PDF we are given an example of how the Cartesian product arises in algebra and how the product can be expressed as a sum of terms.  I am afraid I am not really sure how to ask what I want to ask. but the rest of the question im trying to answer is What Cartesian product do they correspond to? How many times does the term x3 occur?  ( I hope by posting the 2nd half of the question gives insight into my question that I cant seem to ask xD)

Comment: Is there any way you could provide a link to the PDF or provide a screen-shot of the problem in question? It's not clear what the question asks you to do with the term $(x+1)^5$.

Comment: @nomnomnomnom will do, thanks

Comment: A small aside comment since you wrote about $S^5$ to prevent possible future confusion: often the notation $S^n$ is used to denote the $n$-dimensional sphere: $S^n=\{(x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}\in\mathbb R^{n+1}: x_1^2+ \cdots +x_{n+1}^2=1\}$. This has nothing to do with Cartesian product, the same notation is used for something different.

Comment: @omnomnomnom  thank you for the help guys, I had class this morning and was able to talk to my professor about it...in which he basically told me that the pdf he sent out was just one he had used before and that our class hasn't gotten to this subject yet.  I am going to mark noms question as the answer because it has cleared up some of my confusion on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting two totally different ideas confused, which is understandable since the notation is very similar.  The first notion is that of the **arithmetic product** that you're used to, and the second is that of the **cartesian product**.

The **cartesian product** is a neat way of denoting the set of all tuples consisting of elements from particular sets.  Here's how the notation works: let's say $A = \{1,2,3\}$, $B = \{x,y\}$.

The set $A \times B$ would be the set of doubles $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  So, 
$$
A\times B = \{(1,x),(2,x),(3,x),(1,y),(2,y),(3,y)\}
$$
(confusingly, elements like these are occasionally written in the form $a \times b$ rather than $(a,b)$). Similarly, $A \times B \times \mathbb{R}$ would be the set of triples $(a,b,r)$ where $a \in A, b \in B, r \in \mathbb{R}$. You could even take a cartesian product of a set with itself.  So, $B \times B$ would be
$$
\{(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\}
$$
With the usual shorthand, you can write this set as $B \times B = B^2$.  Similarly, we'd have 
$$\overbrace{B \times \cdots \times B}^{n\text{ times}} = B^n
$$
This notion is very much distinct from the **arithmetic product**.  So, for example, $2 \cdot 3$ (which is $6$) means a very different thing than $\{2\}\times \{3\}$ (which is $\{(2,3)\}$) The first is the *arithmetic* product of numbers (or variables representing numbers), whereas the second is the *cartesian* product of sets.  When you are calculating $(x+1)^5$, you are using the *arithmetic* product.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: There is some intersection between Cartesian products and algebra, in that a term in two variables--say, $x^y$--determines a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$; likewise, a term in $n$ variables determines a function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I think one possible mistake being made by the OP is that a function with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not just an n-fold multiple of functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making things confusing and 'overly' theoretical, I would like you to imagine the Cartesian product of two sets in the following way:

$ \mathbb {R}^2 $ when interpreted as Cartesian coordinates is simply TWO axis (or number lines if you will) of real numbers. Imagine one horizontal and one vertical and you got a system that you have been working with since day 1. So when you multiply $ \mathbb{R} \cdot \mathbb{R} $ you get all the coordinates in that good old system. Now imagine $ \mathbb {Z}_+^2$ These are the coordinates of all integers above 0. So you'd start with (1,1), (1,2), (1,infinity), (2,1)...etc.

So what is $ \mathbb{R}^3 $? Slap another axis on there and you are done.

This way, abstract algebra and other subjects become much easier to comprehend rather than trying to come up with some theoretical definition for the sake of complexity.